# Intuition for the optimality of bold play

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, random-walk

There is a standard result (I think originally by Dubins and Savage) that if one wants to maximise the probability of winning a certain amount in an unfair game of chance then an optimal strategy is “bold play”: in each round of play bet the smaller of either your entire wealth or an amount that would ensure that you would achieve your target amount if you win in that round. See for example Section 1.7 of Billingsley's *Probability and Measure*.

In trying to understand this intuitively I came up with this argument:

> If the game is unfair then the expected earnings have a negative trend
>   which is linear over time. On the other hand like any random walk the
>   standard deviation of the earnings is proportionate to the square root
>   of time. If we let enough time to pass the linear will dominate the
>   square root and we will certainly be ruined. So our only hope is to
>   compress the time for which the game is played and the way to do so is
>   to play large stakes.

My question is whether this intuitive argument comes close to what is happening?

Also, is there is a way to turn this argument into a rigorous proof? The idea came to me from knowing that random walks can be embedded into Brownian motion but unfortunately I don't know enough about such embeddings to judge if the reasoning above is sound.

Comment: The original *How to gamble if you must* is well worth reading.

Comment: Your intuitive argument has a point. But if the *only* objective were to make the game short, you'd always bet all you have ...

Comment: that can be easily fixed :-)

Comment: Betting more than the minimum needed to reach the goal is always suboptimal, because in case of losing the result is worse, and it does not increase the probability of winning.  Intuition in the other direction is elusive because of the non-unique optimal strategy.  One might think that prolonging the game is a bad idea, due to the negative drift, and that it is best to win (if one wins) in as few moves as possible.  But the different optimal strategies have different expected time to hit the target.